# struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to upgrade an old Python 2.x class to work with 3.x (written by someone else, and not maintained). Here is a fragment.

```
 def getByte(self):
    if (self.available < 1):
        self.request(4096);
    self.available = self.available - 1
    result = ord(self.bytes[0]);
    self.bytes = self.bytes[1:]
    return result

def request(self, size):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
    contentSize = len(self.user)+len(self.password)+6;
    contentString = "!BHB"+str(len(self.user))+"sB"+str(len(self.password))+"sL"
    data = pack(contentString, 0, contentSize, len(self.user), self.user, len(self.password), self.password, size)
    sock.sendall(data)
    print("Sent!")
    data = sock.recv(6)
    fields = unpack("!BBL", str(data));
    if (fields[0] != 0):
        raise(ServiceDeniedError(fields[0],fields[1]))

    self.bytes = sock.recv(fields[2]);
    self.available = len(self.bytes);
    print("Received: ")
    print(self.available)
    sock.close()
```

Imported and called with `print (rand.getByte())`.
Tracebacks:

```
print (rand.getByte())

self.request(4096);

data = pack(contentString, 0, contentSize, len(self.user), self.user, len(self.password), self.password, size)

struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding it yet? Also, you probably want the length *after* encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Two arguments in the pack() function had to be converted to bytes.

```
data = pack(contentString, 0, contentSize, len(self.user), bytes(self.user, 'utf-8'), len(self.password), bytes(self.password, 'utf-8'), size)
```